# How to use $compile in angularjs with new element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a friendly dialog plugin with angularjs & bootstrap.

I found dialog based in directive was not that easy to use, add a html tag first and define controller and variable, that is too complicated.

So I intend to add a method to angular, create new element dynamic and set variable to root scope, but there seems to be some problems about compile.

Here is mainly code:

```
var defaultOption = {
    title: 'Title',
    content: 'Content',
    backdrop: false,
    buttons: [],
    $dom: null
};

var prefix = '__dialog',
    index = 0;
var newId = function (scope) {
    var id = prefix + index;
    if (!scope[id]) return id;
    index++;
    return arguments.callee(scope);
};

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive('bootstrapModal', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            bootstrapModal: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, $ele) {
            var $dom = $(defaultTemplate),
                body = $ele.children();

            if (body.length) $dom.find('.modal-body').html(body);

            $ele.replaceWith($dom);
            $compile($dom)(scope);

            scope.bootstrapModal.$dom = $dom;
        }
    };
}]);

angular.ui = {};
angular.ui.dialog = function (args) {
    var $body = angular.element(document.body),
        $rootScope = $body.scope().$root,
        option = $.extend({}, defaultOption, args);

    option.id = option.id || newId($rootScope);

    option.show = function () {
        this.$dom.modal('show');
    };

    option.hide = function () {
        this.$dom.modal('hide');
    };

    $body.injector().invoke(function ($compile) {            
        $rootScope[option.id] = option;
        var dialog = '<div bootstrap-modal="{0}"></<div>'.format(option.id);            
        var html = $compile(dialog)($rootScope);
        $('body').append(html);
    });

    return option;
};
$(function () {
    angular.ui.dialog({ //test
        title: 'Alert',
        content: 'test content for alert',
        buttons: [{
            name: 'Close',
            focus: true
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

The entire code is too long, so I put it in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TeddyOY/tsz4z0uL/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: a typo: app.directive('bootstrapModal', ['$compile', function ($complie) <-- $compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `$rootScope.$apply(function() { ... })` around your code where you compile your dialog in `injector().invoke(...)`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4yu0cje/)